# right way to add values in empty column in loop in dataframe , python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
df=pd.DataFrame[columns='one','two','three']

for home in city:
    adres= home
    for a in abc: #abc is pd.Series od names
        #here i want to add values - adress and a , but my dataframe have 3 columns, i will use only 2 here
         df.loc[len(df)]= [adres, a, np.nan]
          print(df)
```

```sh
one, two, three
alabama, flat, NaN
```

How propery should i add values `adres` and `a` to `one` and `two` column in `df` and leave column `three` untouchable?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a pandas series that contain the values and columns I want. for example:

```
new_values= pd.Series(["a", "b"], index=["one", "two"])
```

Then I would append this series to the original dataframe:

```
df= df.append(new_values, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
for i in range(1):
    df.loc[i,['one','two']]=['adress','a']
print(df)
```

---

```
      one two three
0  adress   a   NaN
```