# Update one dataframe value with another dataframe column value based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe say `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1:

id code remarks
1   a12  
2   b32  
3   c12

df2:

id code remarks
1   aaa12  ok
2   b32    done
3   ccc12  not ok
```

I want to update the `df1` remarks value with `df2` remarks value based on the `id` and `code`.

Here second value matches (`id-2 , code-b32`) so update the value of remarks 'done' with `df1` remarks column.

End result of `df1` will be like below,

```
df1:

id code remarks
1   a12  
2   b32  done
3   c12
```

So far i tried like below, I know this is not correct, but i need something like this

```
df1_key = df1['id'].astype(str) + df1['code'].astype(str)
df2_key = df2['id'].astype(str) + df2['code'].astype(str)

df['flag'] = df1_key.isin(df2_key, df1['remarks']=df2['remarks'])
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/python-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th) one i tried the below also, but did n't work for me.

```
 df3 = df1.merge(df2[['remarks']], on=['id','code'], how='left')
```

Comment: @jezrael ; i have updated the question. kindly go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with filtered columns by list:

```
df3 = df1[['id','code']].merge(df2, on=['id','code'], how='left')
```

Or by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df3 = df1.drop('remarks', axis=1).merge(df2, on=['id','code'], how='left')

print (df3)
   id code remarks
0   1  a12     NaN
1   2  b32    done
2   3  c12     NaN
```