# Why does replacing dataframe columns with dictionary just create nan's?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to replace the column 'GeneID' with my dictionary.

This creates just nan's.. Does someone know why this happens?

```
 df
Out[107]: 
        Region     GeneID  DistanceValue
0           BG   79677107            0.0
       ...        ...            ...
1097355  CERus       1415            NaN
[1097360 rows x 3 columns]
```

## replacing it with final_dictionary1

```
df["GeneID"] = df["GeneID"].map(final_dictionary1)

whereas final_dictionary1 looks like:

...
 '52856': 'Mtg2',
 '19886': 'Ros1',
 '16008': 'Igfbp2',
 '14747': 'Cmklr1',
 '13401': 'Dmwd',
 '12545': 'Cdc7',
 '28113': 'Tinf2',
 '71833': 'Dcaf7',
 ...}
```

Is it because the numbers are no strings? Can I see what in df.GeneID is stored?
If it is a number or a string.. Could this cause the error?
Or why isn't it replacing it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problem is traling whitespaces, remove them by `str.strip()`, another problem is value from list not exist in column `GeneID`, so created `NaN`s:

```
df["GeneID"] = df["GeneID"].str.strip().map(final_dictionary1)
```

Or if possible some values not matched and need no replacement of this values:

```
df["GeneID"] = df["GeneID"].str.strip().replace(final_dictionary1)
```

Comment: the second one gives me: 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: @Anja - What is `print (df["GeneID"].dtype)` ?

Comment: object @jezrael

Comment: @Anja - Edited answer.

Comment: This seems to be the right way.. but my notebook is running out of memory.. as it has 1097360 entries in df and 300000 entries in dictionary 

Comment: @Anja - Merge is not possible use like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010406) ?

Comment: Takes 5 minutes and then it deletes every variable I had before.. I think it's a memory problem . What do you thinn @jezrael?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212769/discussion-between-anja-and-jezrael).