# Use fillna() and lambda function in Pandas to replace NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write fillna() or a lambda function in Pandas that checks if 'user_score' column is a NaN and if so, uses column's data from another DataFrame. I tried two options:

```
games_data['user_score'].fillna(
    genre_score[games_data['genre']]['user_score']
    if np.isnan(games_data['user_score'])
    else games_data['user_score'],
    inplace = True
)

# but here is 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'
```

and

```
games_data['user_score'] = games_data.apply(
    lambda row: 
    genre_score[row['genre']]['user_score'] 
    if np.isnan(row['user_score'])
    else row['user_score'],
    axis=1
)

# but here is 'KeyError' with another column from games_data
```

My dataframes:

games_data

[image]

genre_score

[image]

I will be glad for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also [**`fillna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) directly with the `user_score_by_genre` mapping:

```py
user_score_by_genre = games_data.genre.map(genre_score.user_score)
games_data.user_score = games_data.user_score.fillna(user_score_by_genre)
```

BTW if `games_data.user_score` will never deviate from the `genre_score` values, you can skip the `fillna()` and just assign directly to `games_data.user_score`:

```py
games_data.user_score = games_data.genre.map(genre_score.user_score)
```

---

<s>Pandas' built-in [**`Series.where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) also works and is a bit more concise:</s>

<s>`df1.user_score.where(df1.user_score.isna(), df2.user_score, inplace=True)`</s>

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I need. Please check my comment in Mayank Porwal's answer

Comment: @MaxB Looking at it closer, I'm not clear on what the dataframes look like, especially `genre_score`. Could you post some sample rows from both `games_data` and `genre_score`?

Comment: Just did it, you can check the question. Also I get a solution, will post it soon

Comment: @MaxB Looks like you got a working solution already, but just for reference I added another option of using `fillna(user_score_by_genre)` directly.

Comment: @MaxB No problem. BTW is it technically possible for `games_data.user_score` to deviate from the `genre_score` values? If not, you can actually skip the `fillna()` and just assign the mapping directly: `games_data.user_score = games_data.genre.map(genre_score.user_score)`

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, because I fill in the gaps in games_data with the average score for each genre separately from genre_score. And this approach will blur the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df1['user_score'] = np.where(df1['user_score'].isna(), df2['user_score'], df1['user_score'])
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not exactly what I need. df1 and df2 they have different sizes, so I have to select a specific value by key from df2 for every NaN value from df1, as indicated in my example  `df2[ df1['genre'] ]['user_score']`. As. result it can be something like `df1['user_score'] = np.where(df1['user_score'].isna(), df2[df1['genre']]['user_score'], df1['user_score'])`

Answer (score 1):

I found the part of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010443/12778618)

I use series.map:

```
user_score_by_genre = games_data['genre'].map(genre_score['user_score'])
```

And after that I use @MayankPorwal answer:

```
games_data['user_score'] = np.where(games_data['user_score'].isna(), user_score_by_genre, games_data['user_score'])
```

I'm not sure that it is the best way but it works for me.