# Fetch values corresponding to id of each row python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is is possible to fetch column containing values corresponding to an id column?
Example:-

```
df1

|   ID     | Value   | Salary |
|:---------:--------:|:------:|   
|    1     |   amr   | 34     |
|    1     |   ith   | 67     |
|    2     |   oaa   | 45     |
|    1     |   eea   | 78     |
|    3     |   anik  | 56     |
|    4     |   mmkk  | 99     |
|    5     |   sh_s  | 98     |
|    5     |   ahhi  | 77     |
```

```
df2

|   ID     | Dept    |
|:---------:--------:|
|    1     |   hrs   |
|    1     |   cse   |
|    2     |   me    |
|    1     |   ece   |
|    3     |   eee   |
```

```
Expected Output
|   ID     | Dept    | Value     |
|:---------:--------:|----------:|
|    1     |   hrs   | amr       |
|    1     |   cse   | ith       |
|    2     |   me    | oaa       |
|    1     |   ece   | eea       |
|    3     |   eee   | anik      |
```

I want to fetch each values in the 'Value' column corresponding to values in df2's ID column. And create column containing 'Values' in df2. The number of rows in the two dfs are not the same. I have tried

> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th)

Not worked

Comment: do you mean a simple filter? `df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'].tolist())]` ? if you add in your expected output you'll have a perfect [mcve]

Comment: It would help us to understand your question if you would [edit] your question to include the expected output

Comment: I included expected output

Answer (score 2):

IIUC , you can try `df.merge` after assigning a helper column by doing `groupby+cumcount` on ID:

```
out = (df1.assign(k=df1.groupby("ID").cumcount())
       .merge(df2.assign(k=df2.groupby("ID").cumcount()),on=['ID','k'])
       .drop("k",1))

print(out)

   ID Value Dept
0   1   Amr  hrs
1   1   ith  cse
2   2   oaa   me
3   1   eea  ece
4   3  anik  eee
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to do?

```
df1.merge(df2, how='inner',on ='ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have duplicated IDs in both dfs, but these are ordered, try:

```py
df1 = df1.drop(columns="ID")
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```