# Fetch ID corresponding to a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is is possible to fetch column containing values corresponding to an id column?
Example:-

```
df1

|   ID     | Value   | Salary |
|:---------:--------:|:------:|   
|    1     |   amr   | 34     |
|    6     |   ith   | 67     |
|    2     |   oaa   | 45     |
|    1     |   amr   | 78     |
|    3     |   anik  | 56     |
|    4     |   mmkk  | 99     |
|    5     |   sh_s  | 98     |
|    5     |   sh_s  | 77     |
```

```
df2

|   Value  | Dept    | days   |
:----------:---------:--------:
|    amr   |   hrs   | 1      |
|    ith   |   cse   | 2      |
|    oaa   |   me    | 3      |
|    eea   |   ece   | 5      |
|    anik  |   eee   | 6      |
```

```
Expected Output
|   ID     | Dept    | Value     |
|:---------:--------:|----------:|
|    1     |   hrs   | amr       |
|    1     |   cse   | ith       |
|    2     |   me    | oaa       |
|    1     |   ece   | eea       |
|    3     |   eee   | anik      |
```

I want to fetch each values in the 'ID' column corresponding to values in df2's ID column. And create column containing 'ID' in df2. The number of rows in the two dfs are not the same. I have tried

> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th)

I got this error InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th/66898952#66898952

Comment: If check answer from dupe there is explain error and also solution.