# pandas - lookup a value in another DF without merging data from the other dataframe

Tags: pandas, lookup

I have 2 DataFrames. **DF1** and **DF2**.

(Please note that **DF2** has more entries than DF1)

What I want to do is add the nationality column to DF1 (The script should look up the name in DF1 and find the corresponding nationality in DF2).

I am currently using the below code

```
final_DF =df1.merge(df2[['PPS','Nationality']], on=['PPS'], how ='left')
```

Although the nationality column is being added to DF1 the code duplicating entries and also adding additional data from DF2 that I do not want.

Is there a method to get the nationality from DF2 while only keeping the DF1 data?

Thanks

**DF1**

[image: DF1]

**DF2**

[image: DF2]

**OUPUT**

[image]

Comment: Maybe the best is explain why is this not dupe - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010406)

Comment: @jezrael great thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 points, you need to do.

1. If there is any duplicated in the DF2
2. You can define 'how' in the merge statement. so it will look like

   final_DF = DF1.merge(DF2, on=['Name'], how = 'left')

since you want to keep only to DF1 rows, 'left' should be the ideal option for you.

For more info refer [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: great, if this helped then kindly accept the answer and upvote it. Cheers!!

Comment: @amitgrupta is there a way to specify the column you want? for example if there was additional columns in DF2 but I only wanted the nationality column, how would I achieve this?

Comment: yes, like you're already specifying in your code. for ex:
`DF1[col1, col2]. merge(DF2[colx, coly, col1], on = col1, how = 'left')`

or alternatively you can just drop the additional columns after the merge.

Comment: When I use the code I have on another dataframe I have which has multiple columns (I only need the nationality column) there are duplicate entries is there a reason why this might happen?,

Comment: In the merge columns you'll get all the columns from both dataframe if you don't specify. As I said, you can drop the additional columns after the merge using `df_new = df.drop([col to drop], axis =1)` or specify the columns while merging.

Comment: I know I'm able to drop columns, I just can't over come the duplication I am experiencing

Comment: can you paste a screenshot of that, may be I am able to understand it clearly

Comment: please see images of the DFs and the output above. Thanks

Comment: The merge is working perfectly. The issue is with that there are duplicates PPS values in DF2. for ex: There are two 11 in PPS column of DF2, which is getting mapped in the output for 11 PPS value in the DF1