# Why does using merge function in two different dataframes results me more rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of the shape: (4000,3) (2000,3) , with the bellow info and cols:

**df1:**

| imo | speed | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 | 10 |

**df2:**

| imo | dwt | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | test1 |
| 2 | 62 | test2 |
| 3 | 785 | test3 |
| 4 | 353 | test4 |

i would like to add column *dwt* of ***df2*** to ***df1*** based on the same *imo*.

| imo | speed | length | dwt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 52 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 52 |
| 2 | 10 | 10 | 62 |
| 2 | 12 | 10 | 62 |

but when i am trying to do `pd.merge(df1,df2, on = 'imo', how = 'inner')` , the result is much more rows than the original shape of **df1** how is that possible?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Please provide a reproducible sample with more information: python version, pandas version, etc.

Comment: Is imo in df2 unique? If it is not the case then you get a merge on the cross-product for each non unique key.

Comment: @Viktor yes its unique

Comment: then after `pd.merge(df1,df2, on = 'imo', how = 'inner')` you can use `drop_duplicates()` method

Comment: @AnuragDabas the result is much more rows again

Comment: [Check out merge validation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#checking-for-duplicate-keys)

Comment: Try a left merge as follows: df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='imo' , how='left')

Comment: @JHk1821 Please make sure that the values in imo are unique, because the code snippet that you provided should work fine. The only thing that can go wrong is the column 'imo' in df2.

Comment: @AkashDubey the values in imo at df1 there are in multiple rows as you can see from the above table

Comment: @JHk1821 Of course, I did notice that. What I meant was, as long as there are unique values in 'imo' in df2. You should good with both "inner" and "left" merge.

Comment: @AkashDubey yes in df2 imos are unique

Comment: Check cannonical answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternate way, without merge function:

```
dwt_lst = []
for imo in df1.imo.values:
   dwt = df2[df2.imo == imo].dwt.values[0]
   dwt_lst.append(dwt)
df1['dwt'] = dwt_lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `merge` in this way:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='imo').drop(columns='name')
```

Example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'imo': [1,1,2,2], 'speed': [1,2,10,12], 'length': [4,4,10,10]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'imo': [1,2,3,4], 'dwt': [52,62,785,353], 'name': ['test1','test2','test3','test4']})
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='imo').drop(columns='name')
   imo  speed  length  dwt
0    1      1       4   52
1    1      2       4   52
2    2     10      10   62
3    2     12      10   62
```