# Replace entire column with a particular value in each group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace values in `Column1` in each `Group` with the value in `Column1` where `Column0` in that row begins with `Date and Time :`

df:

```
    Column0         Column1         Column2         Column3        Group 
1   Date and Time : 10/01/17,0900   NaN             NaN            A    * value to replace with
2   NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN            A
3   Name            NaN             NaN             NaN            A
                                    ...

1   NaN             NaN             02/06/17,1030   NaN            B
2   Date and Time : 02/06/17,1000   NaN             NaN            B    * value to replace with
3   Details         05/07/17,1330   NaN             NaN            B
4   NaN             01/08/17,1400   Date and Time : NaN            B
                                    ...
```

Expected output:

```
    Column0         Column1         Column2         Column3        Group 
1   Date and Time : 10/01/17,0900   NaN             NaN            A
2   NaN             10/01/17,0900   NaN             NaN            A
3   Name            10/01/17,0900   NaN             NaN            A
                                    ...

1   NaN             02/06/17,1000   02/06/17,1030   NaN            B
2   Date and Time : 02/06/17,1000   NaN             NaN            B
3   Details         02/06/17,1000   NaN             NaN            B
4   NaN             02/06/17,1000   Date and Time : NaN            B
                                    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select rows by condition [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) first in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), create `Series` by `Group` with select `Column1` and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = (df[df['Column0'].str.startswith('Date and Time', na=False)]
       .set_index('Group')['Column1'])
df['Column1'] = df['Group'].map(s)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, do you mind briefly explain your answer? Also can we please select the row where values "begins with" `Date and Time :` instead of `eq`(because there might be some noise)?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - You are right, I overlooked it.

Comment: By `create Series` do you mean `.set_index('Group')`? Do you know any articles or learning resources that explain this technique?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - It means I need mapping by `Group`, so converted `Group` column to index and for `Series` is selected `Column1` - so `s` is Series possible use for mapping by originl column `Group`. This technique is used also if need matching by another DataFrame, like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010406) answer.

Comment: So strange I got error with `df[df['Column0'].str.startswith('Date and Time')]`:  `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`.   Any idea ?   FYI, I just upgraded to Pandas 1.3.0.

Comment: @SeaBean - Ya, then need `na=False` parameter