# How to use Vlookup using pandas without using merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently learning python and DataScience and was trying to make one of my report auto generate the data . However I am not sure how to apply vlookup using pandas. (Note: I dont want to merge the dataset)

Loading Data:
[image]

First Data Set:
[image]

Second Data Set:
[image]

What I am trying to get is the corresponding email address and VP Name from First data Set to Second data set. So the Final data will look like this.
[image]

Vlookup query in excel for fetching email will look like
=VLOOKUP(@A:A,MasterData!A:B,2,0)

Vlookup query in excel for fetching VP name will look like
=VLOOKUP(@A:A,MasterData!A:C,3,0)

Please advise how i can automate this task using pandas without using merge.

I tried using map as recommended in [Pandas: how to merge two dataframes on a column by keeping the information of the first one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th) .
However it is fetching wrong data please find the screenshot

[image]

Comment: If donr need `merge` use double `map`

Comment: need mapping `df2['Full Name'].map` instead `df1['Full Name'].map`

Comment: I tried your suggestion however the data i got in Email and Vp name does not match with the actual dataset. I am not sure if my code is correct. Could you please guide me re-writing the code to get the correct data set?

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael, that helped. Let me apply the same on the full dataset and let you if i notice any issue.

Comment: Hello jezrael, A quick question. With the less data the .map works but when i use .map on a larger set of data i am getting an error,

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: hmmm, it is explain in answer, check again [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010406/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-a-column-by-keeping-the-information-of-th)

Comment: I was able to fix this jezrael, cleaned all the null data and that fixed the issue